# How to create a side navigation menu just like mobile apps?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to create a web app + mobile app (hybrid app). So I started using bootstrap + jQuery + Vuejs for web app. Now I want to create a navigation menu that doesn't drop down but swipes from left-side/right-side as we have seen in several mobile apps. So I decided to use some frameworks to make it like mobile apps and turn to hybrid. There is a list [here](https://superdevresources.com/vuejs-mobile-frameworks) that introduces multiple frameworks for this issue. So first which one is best for hybrid app? The answer is depends on what you need So my needs are very simple let's say I just want a navigation menu to slide from right to left instead of top to down. And again if it's dependable so I have chosen [bootstrap.vuejs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org). Now how can I create that menu? because I couldn't find anything in docs.

Thanks

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Vuetify, it's a component framework that enables you to use a lot of premade components and layouts. In your case the default layouts already have the side menu you mentioned.

Guide: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start

Layouts: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined

Preview: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/dark

I've used it a lot and is really helpful in creating quick layouts. Besides the main layout, you don't need to use anything else from the library.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to use bootstrap if you want customizations on navigation menu. Why don't you make one of your own? here's a link for an example https://vue-burger-menu.netlify.com/